# GDM2 not respecting my conf setting, default blank theme. Lucid OpenBox no gnome-settings-daemon

Tags: 10.04, gdm, openbox

I'm running Lucid and OpenBox, also I dont use gnome-settings-daemon.  I really want to set a background and gtk theme + icons for GDM2.  I have been through the gonf settings, for example,

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 --set --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename /usr/share/backgrounds/ebrit.png
```

If it is relevant my arch is armel.
If my gconf command should have changed my GDM background, please let me know it was correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer... 
I removed GDM2 and installed SLIM.  I would use LightDM for anything newer than lucid.  Although SLIM works great for lucid, and is in repository.  No PPA Builds availble for armel LightDM, and It's frustrating to build on a smartphone like netbook.